# Using Character Position to Search Backward to Find the Position of a Substring

Tags: mysql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Hello I am new in Pyspark. I am trying to do similar thing in Pyspark.

Oracle : `INSTR('Corporate Floor','or', -3, 2)`
result : 2

[the function counts backward from the last character to the third character from the end, which is the first "o" in "Floor". The function then searches backward for the second occurrence of "or", and finds that this second occurrence begins with the second character in the search string.
]

but keep getting error as Instr will only have 2 arguments in Pyspark.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to combine `substring` and `instr` to accomplish this.

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([('Corporate Floor',)],
                           'item : string')

df.selectExpr("item",
              "substring(item,length(item)-2) AS search_item",
              "instr(substring(item,length(item)-2),'or') AS search_loc").show()

#+---------------+-----------+----------+
#|           item|search_item|search_loc|
#+---------------+-----------+----------+
#|Corporate Floor|        oor|         2|
#+---------------+-----------+----------+
```